# C# WCF - ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created (using an online example) a custom binding and I'm trying to use it. Unfortunately I need to register the new binding.

Here is my app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="WCFServiceHost.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ThreadPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <add key="ChunkLength" value="60"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="UdpBinding, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <metadata>
        <wsdlImporters>
          <extension type="UdpTransportBinding.UdpTransportElement, UdpTransportBinding, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </wsdlImporters>
        <policyImporters>
          <extension type="UdpTransportBinding.UdpBindingCollectionElement, UdpTransportBinding, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </policyImporters>
      </metadata>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="TransportService.TransportProtocol" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
        <endpoint name="NetTcpEndPoint" address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="TransportService.ITransportProtocol">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TransportService.ITransportProtocol">
        </endpoint>
         <endpoint name="NetUdpEndpoint" address="" binding="udpTransportBinding" bindingConfiguration="config" contract="TransportService.ITransportProtocol">
         </endpoint>
       </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <bindingElementExtensions>
    <add name="udpTransport" type="UdpTransportBinding.UdpTransportElement, UdpTransportBinding, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </bindingElementExtensions>
  <bindingExtensions>
    <add name="udpTransportBinding" type="UdpTransportBinding.UdpBindingCollectionElement, UdpTransportBinding, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>
<bindings>
  <udpTransportBinding>
    <binding name="config"/>
    <udpTransport/>
  </udpTransportBinding>
</bindings>
```

I've an `app.config` like this, but when I ran the old algorithm I got this error:

> Configuration binding extension
>   system.serviceModel/bindings/udpTransportBinding
>   could not be found. Verify that this
>   binding extension is properly
>   registered in
>   system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions
>   and that it is spelled correctly.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you absolutely sure this is the proper type/assembly information for your class?

> UdpTransportBinding.UdpBindingCollectionElement,
>   UdpTransportBinding, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

One way you can find out exactly where WCF is having a problem is to turn on handling of first chance exceptions and seeing what kind of WCF is getting internally before it reports its nice error. To do this you can disabled "Just My Code" in settings and check off handling of exceptions in the Debug->Exceptions menu.

Second, this config can't be right:

```
<udpTransportBinding>    
    <binding name="config"/>
    <!-- this can't be outside the binding -->    
    <udpTransport/> 
</udpTransportBinding>
```

Are you sure that's exactly what you have? Also why are you creating a binding extension explicitly for udpTransportBinding, but then explicitly declaring that is uses udpTransport inside of it? The whole point of having a predefined binding is that it would automatically select that transport by default. You would really only want users to specify the udpTransport binding element if they defined a custom binding.

Comment: At the beginning i hadn't this part and the error was the same. I've added it following a suggestion found online.

Comment: Well, it would be redundant for you to specify the transport inside a binding which would theoretically exist to configure that transport for you. Let's stick with the exception you're getting though, are you sure the binding collection element is the right assembly/version/publickeytoken? You're not actually required to use the full version spec assembly name format for these specific extensions btw, you could just do "UdpTransportBinding.UdpBindingCollectionElement, UdpTransportBinding". Only behavior extensions require the full version spec (unfortunately).

Comment: nothing to do, also removing these informations nothing changes.

Comment: You're going to have to debug with first chance exceptions turned on to see what problem WCF is having under the covers. I don't see anything wrong with what you're claiming to be doing, so there should be no reason it won't work.